# Input special characters in android WebView

Tags: android, input, webview, special-characters, keyevent

I want to type special characters (such as 'ä', 'é', '£', etc.) in an Android webview.
These characters are not included into the virtual KCM (key characters map). So I can't retrieve the keycode associated to the character and create a KeyEvent.

I tried different methods:

```
String t = "testàaâäù";
char[] charArray = t.toCharArray();
if (charArray.length > 0) {
    KeyCharacterMap keyCharacterMap = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD);
    KeyEvent[] events = keyCharacterMap.getEvents(charArray);
}
// events is null, because some characters aren't include in KCM
// it never works in any case
```

With instrumentation methods:

```
instrumentation.sendStringSync("a");                   // Display 'a'
instrumentation.sendStringSync("àâä");                 // Display nothing
instrumentation.sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_H); // Display 'h'
// Instrumentation seems to use KCM for data entry
```

With ACTION_MULTIPLE KeyEvent:

```
KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), String.valueOf("aàâä"), 0, 0);
focusedView.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
// Doesn't work with WebView, but works with other components such as EditText.
// I get this error: Unimplemented WebView method onKeyMultiple called from: android.webkit.WebView.onKeyMultiple
```

Can I implement the method onKeyMultiple (WebView) to handle data entry? Is there a solution for inputting special characters in the webview? I need a solution that doesn't require root or the creation of a keyboard layout (user hasn't to select the keyboard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when writing with the virtual keyboard on an input field inside a WebView. It would not recognize special characters like "á". What I did:

```
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE) {
    loadUrl("javascript:var prevText = document.activeElement.value;" +
            "var afterText = document.activeElement.value = prevText + \"" + event.getCharacters() + "\";");
    return false;
}
```

When the action is ACTION_MULTIPLE with Javascript I get the input field and I append the special character.

Here is the whole class:

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    public CustomWebView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        ExtenderInputConnection connection = new ExtenderInputConnection(this, false);
        outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH;
        return  connection;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE) {
            loadUrl("javascript:var prevText = document.activeElement.value;" +
                    "var afterText = document.activeElement.value = prevText + \"" + event.getCharacters() + "\";");
            return false;
        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    public class ExtenderInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection implements InputConnection {

        public ExtenderInputConnection(View targetView, boolean fullEditor) {
            super(targetView, fullEditor);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {

            if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
                // backspace
                return super.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)) && super.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
            }
            return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.